# Exception Handling in ASP.NET (C#) from a separate class file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, exception

I am writing an ASP.NET application in C# and I am working on handling possible exceptions that may be thrown from another file.  I have a C# class file that I wrote containing methods that execute SQL commands, and I want to protect against possible exceptions being thrown once my application goes into production.

This is the SQL method I wrote that I am intentionally throwing an error in (From SqlData.cs):

```
public SqlConnection openConnection()
{
        //Create an SQL connection
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("My intentionally incorrect connection string");

        //Open the connection
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException myAppEx)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("There was an error opening the SQL database connection", myAppEx);
        }

        return myConnection;
    }
```

I call this method from my Default.aspx.cs file with the following lines of code:

```
try
{
    //The ReadDT method calls openConnection() in itself
    dt = sqlData.ReadDT(query);
}
catch (ApplicationException exc)
{
    throw exc;
}
```

I am trying to implement Page level exception handling, where if an exception is raised on the current page the Page_Error method is supposed to be called, as cited [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling).  This is why I catch the exception that was thrown from my SqlData.cs class file, and re-throw the exception, so that this exception is seen by the server.  Hence, `Server.GetLastError()` will not return `null`.

As implemented [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling), I have a separate error page that displays all of the information on the exception.  My Page_Error method is as follows:

```
private void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("ErrorPage.aspx?handler=Page_Error%20-%20Default.aspx", true);
}
```

From here the user is redirected to my ErrorPage.aspx and the `SqlException` that was originally thrown is displayed perfectly.

The problem - When I catch the exception from the SqlData.cs, and re-throw the exception, an `UnhandledException` is raised.  if I do not put a try catch block around the ReadDT method call, the same `UnhandledException` is raised from my SqlData.cs file.

Code trace:

1. `throw new ApplicationException("There was an error opening the SQL database connection", myAppEx);` (This works correctly)
2. The exception is then caught and re-thrown (`UnhandledException` occurs)
3. The `Page_Error` method is called as it should be and everything executes properly!

I hope I have been clear in answering myself, I have done a lot of research on exceptions and my particular problem and I have not had any success in finding an answer.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: So your overall goal here is to make sure that user's are redirected to an error page when an exception occurs?

Comment: what about `Application_Exception` in global file?

Comment: Listen to Shekhar... There's a global exception handler in the global.aspx file or whatever it's called... You can use this (I have in the past) to redirect to a custom Error page...

Comment: @Arran - The user is being directed to the error page when an exception occurs, but there in an `UnhandledException` that is being thrown when it shouldn't be.

@Shekhar and @MartinMilan - I have used the Application_Exception method before but the `UnhandledException` exception occurs before the application reaches the `Application_Exception` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with a combination of error handling through Code Level exception handling, and redirecting the user to an error page, then logging the error with ELMAH, to solve my problem.

I now handle all exception's directly in my SqlData class file, for the least yet most efficient code.  I have a global variable `HttpResponse response` in my SqlData class file, that I populate each time I create a new instance of the class from within my ASP.NET application.  So from my Main.aspx.cs file I have something like:

```
private SQLData data;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    data = new SQLData(Response);
    ...
}
```

If I do this I am able to call a `response.Redirect()` from my class file to send the user to my error page, I pass the exception error message and type of exception in a query string, to which I then print out to the user in my error page.  This allows me to display only non-sensitive information to the user.  Therefore the exception has been handled and ELMAH has logged all of the specifics!

```
//Create an SQL connection
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("MyConnString");

//Open the connection
try
{
    myConnection.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Manually log the exception in ELMAH
    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
    //Redirect the user to the error page
    response.Redirect("ErrorPage.aspx?ErrorMessage=" + ex.Message + "&ErrorType=SQLException", true);
}

return myConnection;
```

I then have a link display at the bottom of my error page directing to the `elamh.axd` page only if you are an administrator.  From this page you may view the stack trace and other sensitive information.

You can find information on ELMAH at the bottom of [this](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling) page as well as setting up ELMAH in an ASP.NET application.  It is very easy to do, and a *very* powerful tool.

Cheers,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET, unhandled exceptions thrown by your application will be wrapped in an [HttpUnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpunhandledexception.aspx) before calling the Page or Global error handler.  You need to look at its `InnerException` property to get at the original exception.

In general, you shouldn't bother wrapping and rethrowing exceptions like you're doing unless you're adding value (for example, additional data regarding the context of the exception).  Just let them propagage to wherever they're eventually handled (Page_Error in your case, though you might consider using Application_Error in global.asax.cs, to avoid repeating this error handling code on every page).

Comment: I understand that, but I don't know how to stop it from throwing an `UnhandledException` before it reaches the `Page_Error` or `Application_Error` handlers.

Comment: If you want to stop an error from propagating you can call `Server.ClearError()`, but I don't see why you'd want to do that in your case.  Is the Server.Transfer not working as expected?

Comment: The whole reason I am catching the error and re-throwing it in the `Default.aspx.cs` file is because the exception needs to be thrown in my server file NOT in my SqlData.cs file, otherwise `Server.GetLastError()` will be `null`.  As far as the ASP application is concerned no exception has been thrown when it occurs in my class file.

Comment: "As far as the ASP application is concerned no exception has been thrown when it occurs in my class file." - I don't believe this is true, I suggest you set up a small sample to try to reproduce it.

Comment: With further research I found:  _When throwing an Exception higher, don't:
Throw New ApplicationException(e)
Do:
Throw_

Comment: With further research I found:  **When throwing an Exception higher, don't:
Throw New ApplicationException(e)
Do:
Throw** from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479319.aspx) So I made this change in my SqlData.cs file.  I then proceeded to remove all other try..catch blocks, and eliminated re-throwing the exception, since it is not proper programming practice and should _not_ have to be done.  But with throwing the exception to higher levels ONCE from the lowest level of the application, the `UnhandledException` still occurs.